# Eval insert html into perl cgi-script of running code?

Tags: perl, import, insert, eval

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE, '<', 'evfile';
@file = <FILE>;

$char1 = "123456";
$char2 = "holy cow";
```

I want code of FILE to pop out here and display the variables

```
 $char1 and $char2
```

I've tried the following

```
#1
{eval @file;}

#2
{print (eval @file);}
#3
{for(@file){
print (eval $_;);
}
}
```

I've tried two different things for FILE
making the file a perlscript with a print statement and just a HTML file

#### A

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print BBBBXM
<html>
 <head> 
 <title>A Simple Perl CGI</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>A Simple Perl CGI</h1>  


 <p>$char1   </p>
 <p> $char2 </p> 
</body>
 </html>
BBBBXM
```

#### B

```
html>
 head> 
 title>A Simple Perl CGI</title>
 /head>
 body>
 h1>A Simple Perl CGI</h1>  


 p>$char1   </p>
 p> $char2 </p> 
/body>
 /html>
```

Comment: Now that im reading over this I'm not sure my issue was made clear.  I want to use eval to insert html code into my script.  But i want the "$char" variables to be evaluated and display their set values not just "$char".

Comment: Asking how to do it with `eval` would be some kind of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since you don't really want to evaluate HTML as Perl code. You want to substitude placeholders with strings. :) You want to use a template system like @amon stated below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a mature and stable templating system, take a look at the abundance of available CPAN modules like [Mason](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.20/lib/Mason.pm).

If you're the DIY type:

`eval` treats a *string* (not an array) that it is given as Perl code. Obviously, HTML does not qualify as Perl.

To interpolate a certain placeholder, e.g. something of a `$name` syntax, I'd do this:

```
# hashes are better
my %replacements = (
  char1 => "123456",
  char2 => "holy cow",
);

foreach my $line (@file) {
  $line =~ s{\$(\w+)}{
    exists $replacements{$1}
    ? $replacements{$1}      # substitute, if replacement is defined
    : "$" . $1               # else return the placeholder name
  }ge;                       # /e/xecute replacement
  print $line;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I wanted to answer exactly the same. Another nice way to write the replacement would be `$replacements{$1} // '$' . $1` - it would be almost the same (except someone wants `undef` as a replacement, but a little bit more readable, I think. :)